# Weird audio recorder behaviour - android

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am relatively new to android programming and need a bit of help with this. I am coding an app that records audio but the code crashes when I run the recording code.

Here is the error reported when the app crashes...

> 04-29 19:02:24.833  30257-30257/com.deemo.taglist E/AudioRecordTest﹕ prepare() failed
>   04-29 19:02:24.833  30257-30257/com.deemo.taglist E/MediaRecorder﹕ start called in an invalid state: 4
>   04-29 19:02:24.843  30257-30257/com.deemo.taglist E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException
>               at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
>               at com.deemo.taglist.acts.BpcAct.startRecording(BpcAct.java:335)
>               at com.deemo.taglist.acts.BpcAct.onClick(BpcAct.java:498)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4191)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17184)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

...and here is the ENTIRE activity where the audio recording is executed:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.wesoft.songscrapbook.mods.DataModel;
import com.wesoft.songscrapbook.R;
import com.wesoft.songscrapbook.misc.SongChords;
import com.wesoft.songscrapbook.misc.SongStruct;
import com.wesoft.songscrapbook.misc.SsbAtt;
import com.wesoft.songscrapbook.utils.BestScaler;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class BpcAct extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

BestScaler newScaler = new BestScaler();
private boolean scalingComplete = false;

SsbAtt btnAttributes = new SsbAtt();
DataModel dataModel = new DataModel();

// File ssAudioPath;
ProgressBar recordAudioGuidePB;
EditText songTitle, songLyrics;
Button startRecordBtn, stopRecordBtn, startPlaybackBtn, stopPlaybackBtn, deleteAudioBtn, defineChordsBtn, goToReviewBtn, exitToMainBtn;
TextView songDate, audioCheck, songStructure, songIntroChords, songVerseChords, songChorusChords, songBridgeChords, songOutroChords, audioGuideDuration, audioGuidePBarFill, audioGuideFilePath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Hide the Title Bar of the Application --> Must come before setting the Layout. \\
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    // Hide the Status Bar of Android OS --> Can also be done later. \\
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // Now you can draw the first Layout --> HomeScreen of the Application. \\
    setContentView(R.layout.act_bpc_lyt);

    // Prevent the onboard keyboard from popping up automatically. \\
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);


    // Instantiate (or get references to) all buttons laid out in this Activity. \\
    songTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.song_Title_Input_ET);                        // Do not DELETE. Needed for the 'DataModel.java' class. \\
    songLyrics = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.song_Lyrics_Input_ET);                      // Do not DELETE. Needed for the 'DataModel.java' class. \\
    songDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song_Creation_Date_TV);                       // Do not DELETE. Needed for the 'DataModel.java' class. \\
    audioCheck = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song_Audio_Check_TV);                       // Do not DELETE. Needed for the 'DataModel.java' class. \\
    stopWatch = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.recorder_Chrono_CM);                      // Do not DELETE. Needed for the 'Audio Guide' recorder. \\
    audioGuidePBarFill = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.audio_Guide_PBar_Fill_TV);          // Do not DELETE. Needed for the 'Audio Guide' recorder. \\
    audioGuideFilePath = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.audio_Guide_File_Path_TV);          // Do not DELETE. Needed for the 'Audio Guide' recorder. \\
    recordAudioGuidePB = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.audio_Guide_Create_PB);          // Do not DELETE. Needed for the 'DataModel.java' class. \\
    audioGuideDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recorded_Audio_Guide_Duration_TV);  // Do not DELETE. Needed for the 'Audio Guide' recorder. \\

    songIntroChords = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song_Intro_Input_TV);                  // Do not DELETE. Needed for the 'DataModel.java' class. \\
    songVerseChords = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song_Verse_Input_TV);                  // Do not DELETE. Needed for the 'DataModel.java' class. \\
    songChorusChords = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song_Chorus_Input_TV);                // Do not DELETE. Needed for the 'DataModel.java' class. \\
    songBridgeChords = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song_Bridge_Input_TV);                // Do not DELETE. Needed for the 'DataModel.java' class. \\
    songOutroChords = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song_Outro_Input_TV);                  // Do not DELETE. Needed for the 'DataModel.java' class. \\

    songStructure = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song_Structure_Input_TV);                // Do not DELETE. Needed for the 'DataModel.java' class. \\
    songStructure.setOnClickListener(this);

    startRecordBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_Audio_Record_BTN);
    startRecordBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    stopRecordBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_Audio_Record_BTN);
    stopRecordBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    startPlaybackBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_Audio_Play_BTN);
    startPlaybackBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    stopPlaybackBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_Audio_Play_BTN);
    stopPlaybackBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    deleteAudioBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete_Audio_Guide_BTN);
    deleteAudioBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    defineChordsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.define_Song_Chords_BTN);
    defineChordsBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    goToReviewBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.review_Song_BTN);
    goToReviewBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    exitToMainBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.review_Close_Song_BTN);
    exitToMainBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Deactivate all the buttons in this view by using the 'SsbAtt' class to set 'Alpha' and 'Enable' fields. \\
    btnAttributes.oneButtonSetAlpha35(startPlaybackBtn);
    btnAttributes.oneButtonSetAlpha35(deleteAudioBtn);

    // Set the Visibility of the 'Start Audio Play' button to 'GONE'. \\
    stopRecordBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    stopPlaybackBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    // Set the 'Audio Guide Progress Bar' length to 2 minutes (i.e. 120 000 milliseconds). \\
    recordAudioGuidePB.setMax(120000);


    // Create the main folder on the devices external storage (if available) for storing NB Song Scrapbook data. \\
    if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) // Check if SD card is mounted. \\
    {

        // Set up a reference to the directories you want to create for access by or via this Activity - for saving data to or retrieving data from. \\
        File ssAudioPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Song Scrapbook/Audio Guides");

        if(!(ssAudioPath).exists()) {  // If the directory linked to 'ssAudioPath' already exits, do nothing and simply use that as the destination folder. \\
            ssAudioPath.mkdirs();      // If the directory linked to 'ssAudioPath' does not already exit...then create the directory. \\
        } else;


    } else;

     // ---------------------------------------------------------------- Data Fetching Section - START --------------------------------------------------------------------- \\

    /** Check to see if any data was passed from the previous Activity...if TRUE, then extract all data from the data bundle received **/
    if(getIntent().getExtras() != null) { // Check to see if there is any data in the default Activity Data Object. \\

        // Create a new bundle object and add to it the data passed from the previous activity...
        Bundle dataIn = getIntent().getExtras();

        // Update the relevant UI fields with the data passed from the previous activity...
        dataModel.importBpcData(dataIn, songTitle, songDate, songStructure, songIntroChords, songVerseChords, songChorusChords, songBridgeChords, songOutroChords, songLyrics, audioCheck, audioGuideDuration, audioGuidePBarFill, audioGuideFilePath);
    } else;

   // ---------------------------------------------------------------- Data Fetching Section - END ----------------------------------------------------------------------- \\

    if(audioCheck.getText().length() == 3) {

        // [1] Set the file path of the 'Audio Guide' linked to this song entry. \\
        agFileName = (String) audioGuideFilePath.getText();

        // [2] Update the 'Audio Guide' Record ProgressBar status. \\
        String getPbarFill = (String) audioGuidePBarFill.getText();
        recordAudioGuidePB.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(getPbarFill));

        // [3] Activate the 'Playback' and 'Delete' buttons. \\
        btnAttributes.oneButtonSetAlpha100(deleteAudioBtn);
        btnAttributes.oneButtonSetAlpha100(startPlaybackBtn);

        // [4] Deactivate the 'Audio Record' buttons. \\
        btnAttributes.oneButtonSetAlpha35(startRecordBtn);

        // Toast tst = Toast.makeText(this, "Value:  " + getPbarFill, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        // tst.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
        // tst.show();
    } else;
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    if (!scalingComplete) // only do this once!!
    {
        newScaler.scaleContents(findViewById(R.id.songCreationContents), findViewById(R.id.songCreationContainer));
        scalingComplete = true;
    }
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}

// Called when the views have been created. We override this in order to scale the UI, which we can't do before this.
@Override
public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);
    return view;
}


// ----------------------------------------------------------- Audio Guide RECORD, Play and Delete Code START ------------------------------------------------------------- \\

long elapsedTimeBeforeStop;
private MediaPlayer mPlayer = null;
private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
private static String agFileName = null;


private final int TIMER_TICK = 1000;                        // Tells the TIMER to fire/tick ONCE every SECOND, decrease this to fire more frequently. \\
Timer progressBarAdvancer;
CountDownTimer recordingCountDown;
private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest";

// Needed for updating the recording 'Audio Guide' progress. \\
int countUp;
private Chronometer stopWatch = null;                       // Initialize a chronometer for count the time lapsed. \\

private int startCounter () {

    stopWatch.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chrono) {
            countUp = (int) ((SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chrono.getBase()) / 1000);
            int minutes = (countUp / 60);
            int seconds = (countUp % 60);
            audioGuideDuration.setText(String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds));
        }
    });

    // Quickly reset the 'Counter' before starting it up again. This will ensure a clean start time everytime. \\
    resetCounter();

    // Start counting the time elapsed. \\
    stopWatch.start();

    // Start the updating of the Audio Guide recording progress bar. \\
    updateAudioRecordProgress();

    // Serve the 'countUp' object while the timing is in progress. \\
    return countUp;
}

private void startRecordingCountDownTimer() {

    recordingCountDown = new CountDownTimer(121000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            // mTextField.setText("done!");
            stopRecording();
        }
    }.start();
}

private long stopCounter () {

    stopWatch.stop();

    // Get an immediate reference to the current 'SystemClock' time, and log that into the 'elapsedTimeBeforeStop' time object. \\
    long elapsedTimeBeforeStop = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - stopWatch.getBase();
    return elapsedTimeBeforeStop;
}

private void stopRecordingCountDownTimer() {

    // [1] Stop the 'recordingCountDown' counter. \\
    recordingCountDown.cancel();
}

private void resetCounter () {

    // Reset the 'stopWatch' to get a new start time. \\
    stopWatch.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - elapsedTimeBeforeStop);
}

public void createNewAudioID() {

    // Check if the 'audioGuideFilePath' hasn't already been defined and create a new file path if not already defined. \\
    if(audioGuideFilePath.getText() == "") {

        // [1] Create an ID for the 'Audio Guide' using the 'Song Title' of the song. \\
        String songTitleWowSpace = songTitle.getText().toString().replace(" ", "");
        String songIDPart1 = songTitleWowSpace.substring(0, 3);   // Splice 1 - Take the first 3 characters of the 'Song Title' string. \\
        String songIDPart2 = songTitleWowSpace.substring(songTitleWowSpace.length() - 3, songTitleWowSpace.length());  // Splice 2 -  Take the last 3 characters of the 'Somg Title' string. \\
        String songIDPart3 = songTitleWowSpace.substring(songTitleWowSpace.length()-3, songTitleWowSpace.length()-2);  // Splice 3 - Take the 3rd last character of the 'Song Title' string. \\
        String songID = songIDPart1 + songIDPart3 + songIDPart2 + ".3gp";  // Stitch all splices (i.e. 1, 2 & 3) together to create a new UNIQUE 'Song ID' string for the 'Audio Guide'. \\

        // [2] Get a reference to the 'Audio Guide' directory for saving the audio recording to. \\
        agFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Song Scrapbook/Audio Guides";
        agFileName += "/" + songID;

        // [3] Set the 'audioGuideFilePath' value to that of the 'agFileName' string object. \\
        audioGuideFilePath.setText(agFileName);

        /**Toast tst = Toast.makeText(this, "Created:  " + agFileName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        tst.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
        tst.show(); **/
    } else;
}

private void getSongCreationDate() {

    // [1] Get an instance to the System Calendar, extract current date and insert it into the 'currDate' string object. \\
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    // [2] Define a date format, apply it to the 'currDate' string and insert it into another string object (i.e. ''). \\
    SimpleDateFormat dateForm = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
    String songCreationDate = dateForm.format(cal.getTime());

    // [3] Set the value/text of the 'songDate' to the newly created 'songCreationDate' string result. \\
    songDate.setText(songCreationDate);

    /** Toast tst = Toast.makeText(this, "Created:  " + songCreationDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    tst.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
    tst.show(); **/
}

public void startRecording() {

    createNewAudioID();

    // Create a new Media Recorder and get the recording process in motion. \\
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setMaxDuration(120000);
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(agFileName);

    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }

    // Start audio recording. \\
    mRecorder.start();

    // Start the clock to time the duration of the recording. \\
    startCounter();

    // Start the countdown to make sure recording doesn't exceed 2 minutes. \\
    startRecordingCountDownTimer();
}

public void stopRecording() {

    // Stop the audio recorder timer. \\
    stopCounter();

    // Stop and clean the 'Audio Guide' progressbar updating process. \\
    progressBarAdvancer.cancel();
    progressBarAdvancer.purge();

    // Stop the recorder CountDownTimer. \\
    stopRecordingCountDownTimer();

    mRecorder.stop();
    mRecorder.release();
    mRecorder = null;

    // [1] Make the 'stopRecordBtn' button invisible and the 'startRecordBtn' button visible. \\
    startRecordBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                                                  // Set visibility to GONE. \\
    stopRecordBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);                                                      // Set visibility to VISIBLE. \\

    // [2] Re-enable ALL other views to prevent interruption of the current Audio Process. \\
    songTitle.setEnabled(true);
    songLyrics.setEnabled(true);
    goToReviewBtn.setEnabled(true);
    exitToMainBtn.setEnabled(true);
    songStructure.setEnabled(true);
    defineChordsBtn.setEnabled(true);

    // [3] Deactivate the 'Audio Record' button. \\
    btnAttributes.oneButtonSetAlpha35(startRecordBtn);

    // [4] Activate the following buttons. \\
    btnAttributes.oneButtonSetAlpha100(startPlaybackBtn);
    btnAttributes.oneButtonSetAlpha100(deleteAudioBtn);
    btnAttributes.oneButtonSetAlpha100(goToReviewBtn);
    btnAttributes.oneButtonSetAlpha100(exitToMainBtn);

    // [5] Insert the 'Yes' text into the 'audioCheK' TextView. \\
    audioCheck.setText("Yes");
}

public void startPlaying() {

    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        mPlayer.setDataSource(agFileName);
        mPlayer.prepare();
        mPlayer.start();
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }
}

public void stopPlaying() {

    mPlayer.release();
    mPlayer = null;
}

public void deleteAudioGuide() {

    // [1] Create a new File object and delete the value inserted into it by the 'createNewAudioID()' function. \\
    File thisAG = new File(agFileName);
    thisAG.delete();

    // [2] Clear the 'Audio Guide' progress bar. \\
    recordAudioGuidePB.setProgress(0);

    // [3] Reset the 'stopWatch' to get a new start time. \\
    resetCounter();

    // [4] Clear the 'Audio Guide' recording duration time. \\
    audioGuideDuration.setText("0:00");

    // [5] Insert the 'No' text into the 'audioCheK' TextView. \\
    audioCheck.setText("No");
}

public void updateAudioRecordProgress() {

    progressBarAdvancer = new Timer();

    progressBarAdvancer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {

            // [1] Run the timer for every 1000 milliseconds = 1 second. \\
            int runProgress = recordAudioGuidePB.getProgress() + TIMER_TICK;

            recordAudioGuidePB.setProgress(runProgress);
        }
    },
            1000, // Delay before first execution
            TIMER_TICK);
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------ Audio Guide RECORD, Play and Delete Code END -------------------------------------------------------------- \\


@Override
public void onClick (View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.song_Structure_Input_TV) {

        // Create a bundle object. \\
        Bundle dataKeeper = new Bundle();

        // Get the NB data and pass it to the next Activity. \\
        dataModel.exportBpcData(dataKeeper, songTitle, songDate, songStructure, songIntroChords, songVerseChords, songChorusChords, songBridgeChords, songOutroChords, songLyrics, audioCheck, audioGuideDuration, recordAudioGuidePB, audioGuideFilePath);

        // Start new intent to move from the current activity to the next activity...
        Intent Bpc2SS = new Intent(BpcAct.this, SongStruct.class);
        Bpc2SS.putExtras(dataKeeper);
        startActivity(Bpc2SS);
    }

    else if (v.getId() == R.id.define_Song_Chords_BTN) {

        // Create a bundle object. \\
        Bundle dataKeeper = new Bundle();

        // Get the NB data and pass it to the next Activity. \\
        dataModel.exportBpcData(dataKeeper, songTitle, songDate, songStructure, songIntroChords, songVerseChords, songChorusChords, songBridgeChords, songOutroChords, songLyrics, audioCheck, audioGuideDuration, recordAudioGuidePB, audioGuideFilePath);

        // Start new intent to move from the current activity to the next activity...
        Intent Bpc2SC = new Intent (BpcAct.this, SongChords.class);
        Bpc2SC.putExtras(dataKeeper);
        startActivity(Bpc2SC);
    }

    else if (v.getId() == R.id.start_Audio_Record_BTN) {

        if (songTitle.length() == 0) {   // Check to see if the 'Song Title' EditText is empty. \\

            // If the 'Song Title' is empty, then show a warning message to the user. \\
            Toast tost = Toast.makeText(this, "Please create a  Song Title  first.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            tost.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
            tost.show();
        }

        else if (songTitle.length() <= 3) {   // Check to see if the 'Song Title' EditText is shorter than 3 characters. \\

            // If the 'Song Title' is empty, then show a warning message to the user. \\
            Toast tost = Toast.makeText(this, "The  Song Title  must be longer than 3 characters.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            tost.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
            tost.show();
        }

        else if (songTitle.length() > 3) {   // Check to see if the 'Song Title' EditText is longer than 3 characters. \\

            // [1] Start the recording the 'Audio Guide' file for the current song. \\
            startRecording();
        }
    }

    else if (v.getId() == R.id.stop_Audio_Record_BTN) {

        // [1] Deactivate the 'Audio Record' button. \\
        btnAttributes.oneButtonSetAlpha35(startRecordBtn);

        // [2] Activate the following buttons. \\
        btnAttributes.oneButtonSetAlpha100(startPlaybackBtn);
        btnAttributes.oneButtonSetAlpha100(deleteAudioBtn);
        btnAttributes.oneButtonSetAlpha100(goToReviewBtn);
        btnAttributes.oneButtonSetAlpha100(exitToMainBtn);

        // [3] Stop the recording the 'Audio Guide' file for the current song. \\
        stopRecording();
    }

    else if (v.getId() == R.id.start_Audio_Play_BTN) {

        // [1] Start playback of the 'Audio Guide' file for the current song. \\
        startPlaying();

        // [2] Make the 'stopRecordBtn' button visible and make the 'startRecordBtn' button invisible. \\
        stopPlaybackBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        startPlaybackBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        // [3] Deactivate the 'DELETE Audio Guide' button. \\
        btnAttributes.oneButtonSetAlpha35(deleteAudioBtn);
    }

    else if (v.getId() == R.id.stop_Audio_Play_BTN) {

        // [1] Stop playback of the 'Audio Guide' file for the current song. \\
        stopPlaying();

        // [2] Make the 'stopRecordBtn' button visible and make the 'startRecordBtn' button invisible. \\
        startPlaybackBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        stopPlaybackBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // [3] Reactivate the 'DELETE Audio Guide' button. \\
        btnAttributes.oneButtonSetAlpha100(deleteAudioBtn);
    }

    else if (v.getId() == R.id.delete_Audio_Guide_BTN) {

        // [1] Delete the relevant 'Audio Guide' file from the storage folder. \\
        deleteAudioGuide();

        // [2] Re-Activate the 'Record Audio' button. \\
        btnAttributes.oneButtonSetAlpha100(startRecordBtn);

        // [3] Deactivate the 'Delete Audio Guide' and 'Play Audio Guide' buttons. \\
        btnAttributes.oneButtonSetAlpha35(deleteAudioBtn);
        btnAttributes.oneButtonSetAlpha35(startPlaybackBtn);
    }

    else if (v.getId() == R.id.review_Song_BTN) {

        // [1] Check if the 'getSongCreationDate' object is empty and insert the current date into the object. \\
        if(songDate.getText().length() == 0) {
            // Create a new song creation date (i.e. insert current date) by executing the 'getSongCreationDate()' function. \\
            getSongCreationDate();
        }else;

        // [2] Create a bundle object...
        Bundle dataKeeper = new Bundle();

        // [3] Get the NB data and pass it to the next Activity. \\
        dataModel.exportBpcData(dataKeeper, songTitle, songDate, songStructure, songIntroChords, songVerseChords, songChorusChords, songBridgeChords, songOutroChords, songLyrics, audioCheck, audioGuideDuration, recordAudioGuidePB, audioGuideFilePath);

        // [4] Start new intent to move from the current activity to the next activity. \\
        Intent bpc2bpr = new Intent (BpcAct.this, BprAct.class);
        bpc2bpr.putExtras(dataKeeper);
        startActivity(bpc2bpr);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_right_in, R.anim.slide_left_out);
    }

    else if (v.getId() == R.id.review_Close_Song_BTN) {

        Intent bpc2main = new Intent (BpcAct.this, MainAct.class);
        bpc2main.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(bpc2main);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_right_out, R.anim.slide_left_in);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_right_out, R.anim.slide_left_in);
}
}
```

I have been struggling with this for a while now and I really don't know where the problem could be. The odd things that I have two physical devices (Galaxy Mega 6.3 and Galaxy X-Cover 2) on which I test the application every now and then. The application seems to run fine on the Mega 6.3 (which runs Android 4.2.2), but crashes every time when I run it on the X-cover 2 (which is running Android 4.1.2). Note problem also only happens when I hit the audio record button. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: prepare() can fail if it's called at the wrong time or if a device thinks that some of your parameters are set incorrectly. Different devices support different settings for recordings. Your code must be versatile enough to handle them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 private void startRecord(){

      File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.pcm"); 

      try {
       file.createNewFile();
       recording=true;
       OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
       BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
       DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(bufferedOutputStream);

       int minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(44100, 
         AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, 
         AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

       short[] audioData = new short[minBufferSize];

       AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
         44100,
         AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
         AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
         minBufferSize);
       //int sessionId=audioRecord.getAudioSessionId();
     //  NoiseSuppressor.create(sessionId);
       audioRecord.startRecording();

       while(recording){
        int numberOfShort = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0, minBufferSize);
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfShort; i++){
         dataOutputStream.writeShort(audioData[i]);
        }
       }

       audioRecord.stop();
       dataOutputStream.close();

      } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }

     }
```

here by using this function raw data of recording(PCM) will be saved in external directory. you should play this recording by using AudioTrack object.

Comment: I have selected this as the solution (answer) to my recording problem, but that doesn't mean that I like this option. Two reasons for not liking this: [1] the size of the recorded PCM file is very large - even when just recording 1 minute of audio; and [2] I had some difficulties with fully ending the recording session. Maybe it's something I did incorrectly in my code...who knows. But in the end I reverted back to using the MediaRecord option rather using the AudioRecord process discussed here.

Comment: Yes mediarecorder is high level api and save us from very complexity but this solution help us when we dont want to record sound from mic.like in piano apps

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is wrong with the mRecorder, but I usually use an AudioRecord object for recording audio rather then the full blown MediaRecorder which can potentially do a lot more then just record audio. Either way check out the android dev page for AudioRecord http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html hope that helps.

P.S. found this graph on the states of the media recorder  http://developer.android.com/images/mediarecorder_state_diagram.gif
if you don't like the AudioRecord this chart may be able to help you debug where you MediaRecorder is getting put in an invalid state

Comment: Useful advice. Will definitely look into this option. Thanks